# Не сохраняется массив данных полей (сохраняет или первый или последний)

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины

Не могу понять ошибку.

У меня есть метабокс полей для вордпреса к нему я приделал repeator (на js)
И я не могу сохранить массив данных полей (сохраняет или первый или последний).
C foreach - такая-же беда.

```
<h4><?php _e('Kierunki sudiow', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></h4>
<span><?php _e('For multiselect please press CTRl and do your  chose', '') ?></span>
<?php $returnedValues = return_informator_values(); ?>
<div class="admin-container">
    <div class="adm-item">
        <label>
            <span><?php _e('Typ kierunków', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <select class="parent" name="informator[specialnosc]" value="<?php echo $returnedValues[0]['specialnosc'] ?>">
                <?php foreach ($kirynky as $kirynok): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $kirynok->name ?>"><?php echo $kirynok->name ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span><?php _e('text input', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <input type="text" name="informator[text]" placeholder="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'text',true)?>" >

        </label>

        <label>
            <span><?php _e('Kierunki', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <select name="informator[kierynok]" value="<?php echo $returnedValues[0]['specialnosc'] ?>">
                <?php foreach ($kirynky as $kirynok): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $kirynok->name ?>"><?php echo $kirynok->name ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span><?php _e('    Nabór', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <select name="informator[recrut]" multiple size="1">
                <?php foreach ($recrut as $time): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $time->name ?>"><?php echo $time->name ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span><?php _e('Rodzaj studiow', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <?php $styd = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'informator', true) ?>
            <select name="informator[typ]" multiple size="1">
                <option
                        value="<?php _e('Stacionarne', 'pageart-studying-room') ?>" <?php checked($styd, ''); ?>><?php _e('Stacionarne', 'pageart-studying-room') ?>
                </option>
                <option value="<?php _e('Zaoczne', 'pageart-studying-room') ?>" <?php checked($styd, ''); ?>><?php _e('Zaoczne', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></option>
            </select>
        </label>

        <label>
            <span><?php _e('Tytul. lic', 'pageart-studying-room') ?></span>
            <?php $tytyl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'informator', true) ?>
            <select name="informator[tityl]" multiple size="1">
                <option value="INZ">INZ</option>
                <option value="MGR">MGR</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label class="btns">
            <a class="btn-repeat">+</a>
            <a class="btn-delete">-</a>
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" name="informator_fields_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(__FILE__); ?>"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Это функция сохранения

```
function informator_extra_fields_update($post_id){
    $metakey = 'informator';
    if (isset($_POST[$metakey]) && is_array($_POST[$metakey])) {
        $fields = $_POST[$metakey];
        $fields = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $fields); 
        $fields = array_filter($fields);
        update_post_meta($post_id, $metakey, $fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: какие данные вы получаете в этом месте $_POST[ $metakey ]? есть вероятность что array_filter удаляет элемент массива когда в значении этого элемента следующие данные: false, -1, '','0',0, null

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'specialnosc' => string 'pedagog-malarstwa' (length=17)
      'text' => string 'авываываыав' (length=22)
      'kierynok' => string 'pedagog-malarstwa' (length=17)
      'recrut' => string 'agust' (length=5)
      'typ' => string 'Stacionarne' (length=11)
      'tityl' => string 'INZ' (length=3)
Я  получаю вот  такой массив, но конечно-же их дожно быть больше .

Comment: массив такой же перед сохранением в бд? update_post_meta сереализирует массив, поэтому eсть вероятность что перед сохранением у вас удаляется часть данных.

Comment: Теоретично - да , но  дебагером  не проверял.  На время сделал не большой  костыль , но это не  выход :). Костыль  заключается в add_post_meta().